# Getting plugin functions on Typescript

Tags: cordova, typescript, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I am trying to use some cordova plugins functions on a typescript file but i can't build the file. Imagine that I want to access the device platform and model. Can someone help me with this? Should I create interfaces for every function on js files of the plugin?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

There are already definitions for that : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/cordova/plugins/Device.d.ts

```
interface Device {
    /** Get the version of Cordova running on the device. */
    cordova: string;
    /**
     * The device.model returns the name of the device's model or product. The value is set
     * by the device manufacturer and may be different across versions of the same product.
     */
    model: string;
    /** device.name is deprecated as of version 2.3.0. Use device.model instead. */
    name: string;
    /** Get the device's operating system name. */
    platform: string;
    /** Get the device's Universally Unique Identifier (UUID). */
    uuid: string;
    /** Get the operating system version. */
    version: string;
}

declare var device: Device;
```

You simply reference this file (using `///<reference` comment) and then you can do:

```
console.log(device.model,device.platform);
```