# Typescript compiler/Cordova API: Check for undefined global variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, typescript

I'm new to Typescript, or better in Angular 2 with Typescript.

The problem is that I cannot compile my code due to undefined Cordova API  global variables in my local dev environment.
These variables will be obviously defined once the app will be compiled and packed for production, so with Cordova libraries.

For example, with Angular 1 and Javascript I could have this:

```
if (typeof(device) != 'undefined') {
    return device.platform;
}
```

Now with Angular 2 and TypeScript compiler tells me that it cannot find name device.

How to work so with these unavailable variables in dev environment?
(I just build and test my app on the browser first)

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339740/getting-plugin-functions-on-typescript might be of interest for you

Comment: Thank you , this was what I needed!

Comment: Glad it helped! Make sure to upvote the answer if it helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is in the [Ionic 2 docs for device plugin](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/device/). What you need to do is import the Device class from ionic-native and call the uuid property of the device object.

For example

```
import {Device} from 'ionic-native';

platform.ready().then(() => {
   console.log(Device.device.uuid);
}
```

Comment: I don't use Ionic, that's the problem.. :/
I build my UI manually with Bootstrap and other few libs!

Comment: Thanks anyway but what @Phonolog suggested was what I was looking for!